# how to allocate memory dynamically for pointers and three dimensional arrays

Tags: c, for-loop, multidimensional-array, malloc, double-pointer

I want to *allocate memory dynamically* using `malloc` so that i can use *for loop* to access each array and array element.

My code looks like this:

```
long naxes1[3]  = {1,1,1}, naxes2[3]  = {1,1,1}, naxes3[3]  = {1,1,1}, naxes4[3]  = {1,1,1}; //upto naxes20
```

Another line of code is:

```
double *pix1,  *pix2,  *pix3,  *pix4,  *pix5; //upto *pix20
```

To allocate the memory, I do this:

```
pix1  = (double *) malloc(npixels * sizeof(double));        
pix2  = (double *) malloc(npixels * sizeof(double));//20 times,
```

How can we use for loop to allocate memory for pixels instead of this?

moreover,

```
#include"cfitsio.h"
long        npixels = 1;
fits_read_pix(names[0], TDOUBLE, firstpix, npixels, NULL, pix1, NULL, &status)
```

here, names[i] are names of fitsfile inputs, TDOUBLE is double type, first pixels, npixels, etc are local variables inside C library routine cfitsio.h

Comment: You should just post the entire piece of code, like this is harder to follow, for example, what is the  `npixles` you use in the `malloc`?

Comment: Are you asking how to set up an array of pointers to double?

Comment: [don't cast malloc](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you have written variable names `naxes1`, `naxes2`, …, `naxes20`, you need to rewrite the code to use an array.  If you need indexes `1..20`, then you could write:

```
int naxes[21][3] = { { -1, -1, -1 },  /* Element 0 - unused */
                     { 1, 1, 1 }, { 1, 1, 1 }, { 1, 1, 1 }, { 1, 1, 1 },
                     { 1, 1, 1 }, { 1, 1, 1 }, { 1, 1, 1 }, { 1, 1, 1 },
                     { 1, 1, 1 }, { 1, 1, 1 }, { 1, 1, 1 }, { 1, 1, 1 },
                     { 1, 1, 1 }, { 1, 1, 1 }, { 1, 1, 1 }, { 1, 1, 1 },
                     { 1, 1, 1 }, { 1, 1, 1 }, { 1, 1, 1 }, { 1, 1, 1 },
                   };
```

Or, using a very sensible and convenient GCC [extension](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-5.2.0/gcc/Designated-Inits.html#Designated-Inits):

```
int naxes[21][3] = { [0] = { -1, -1, -1 }, [1 ... 20] = { 1, 1, 1 }, };
```

The range notation `[1 ... 20]` is the extension; the `[0] = { -1, -1, -1 },` is standard C99 — a designated initializer.

With this, you can use `naxes[n][m]` for `n` in the range `1..20` and `m` in the range `0..2` to access the elements of `naxes`.

Similar comments apply to the `pixN` variables.  However, there you want dynamic memory allocation; you might then use:

```
double *pix_base = malloc(20 * npixels * sizeof(double));
if (pix_base == 0) { …handle out of memory error… }

double  pix[21];
pix[0] = 0;
for (int i = 1; i < 21; i++)
    pix[i] = pix_base + (i - 1) * npixels;
```

You can now use `pix[n][m]` for `n` in the range `1..20` and `m` in the range `0..(npixels-1)` to access the data.  When finished, you call `free(pix_base)` to free all the memory at once.  This is more economical on space than 20 separate memory allocations (and more economical on calls to `malloc()` and `free()`).

You can adapt this second technique to handle the arrays of integers too.

If you can use entries 0..19 instead of 1..20, then you can save a little complexity.

Comment: then how to free the memory, like this?  for (int i = 1; i < 21; i++)
  free(  pix[i])

Comment: I said `free(pix_base)`; the `naxes` array is an automatic (or `static`) array and does not need freeing.

Comment: i did like this: where N = 20;   'double *pix[N];  
    for (int i=0;i<N;i++) 
    {
        pix[i] = calloc(npixels, sizeof(double));
        if (pix[i] == NULL) 
        {
            printf("Error: allocating memory to pixels failed");
            return (1);
        }
    } then, to free the memory for(j=0;j<N;j++)
        {
            free(pix[j]);
        }'

Answer (score 1):

You likely did a lot of copying and pasting to come up with that code. Well let's use that systematic logic of yours and separate out repeated logic, with the aid of some 2D arrays:

```
long naxes[20][3];
const long naxes_init[3] = {1, 1, 1};

for (int i = 0; i < 20; ++i)
{
    memcpy(naxes[i], naxes_init, 3 * sizeof (long));
}

double *pix[20];

for (int i = 0; i < 20; ++i)
{
    pix[i]  = (double *) malloc(npixels * sizeof(double));
}
```

You already have most of the logic down: you just need to understand for-loop syntax. After all, the line in the second loop is almost exactly what you had copied 20 times earlier.

Lastly, a key difference is that of course C uses 0-based indices... and so should you. e.g. `pix[0]` is the equivalent to your `pix1`.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
double *pix[20];
int i;
for (i=0;i<20;i++) {
    pix[i] = calloc(npixels, sizeof(double));
    if (pix[i] == NULL) {
        perror("calloc failed");
        exit(1);
    }
}
```

I'm using `calloc` instead of `malloc` because the former is geared toward creating an array, and has the side effect of initializing all bytes to zero.

Comment: Why would you assume that it needs to be initialized to 0s.  If you are going to initialize it immediately, its just a wasted call to memset at best and possibly preventS the compiler from doing optimizations using its malloc builtins.